# Returns 404 even if MVC files are setup properly in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

My code igniter project is returning 404 whenever I use method that I created in controllers. I have it running on Mac OS Mojave on Apache2.
There might be configuration or setting that I missed.

The codeigniter page works fine when opening http://localhost/myproject where I see the welcome page.
I have a 404 problem when I start using the new controller class. To make it simple, I created below "Pages.php" controller file inside application/controllers folder:

```
<?php
class Pages extends CI_Controller {

        public function view()
        {
        echo "running the view method";

        }
}
```

I expected the page to display "running the view method"
but the result is a 404 page at http://localhost/myproject/view or http://localhost/myproject/index.php/view.

Answer (score 0):

it works by adding below in route.php

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/$1';
```